# Applicative instance for non-empty leafy tree in Haskell

Tags: haskell, binary-tree, applicative

Given the following data type:

```
data Tree a =
    Branch (Tree a) (Tree a)
  | Leaf a deriving (Eq, Show)
```

And the following Functor instance :

```
instance Functor Tree where
  fmap f (Leaf a)       = Leaf $ f a
  fmap f (Branch t1 t2) = Branch (fmap f t1) (fmap f t2)
```

How to implement best the Applicative instance for this tree?
I came up with:

```
instance Applicative Tree where
  pure = Leaf

  Leaf f       <*> t            = f <$> t
  Branch t1 t2 <*> Leaf a       = t1 <*> Leaf a
  Branch t1 t2 <*> Branch t3 t4 = Branch (t1 <*> t3) (t2 <*> t4)
```

Even if it compiles, I'm very suspicious about this implementation.
I don't know if this `Branch (Leaf (+1)) (Leaf (+2)) <*> Leaf 7` should return `Leaf 8` (find the closest function to apply) or duplicate and return `Branch (Leaf 8) (Leaf 9)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Even if it compiles, I'm very suspicious about this implementation. I don't know if this Branch (Leaf (+1)) (Leaf (+2)) <*> Leaf 7 should return Leaf 8 (find the closest function to apply) or duplicate and return Branch (Leaf 8) (Leaf 9)

Reasonable instances should follow [Applicative functor laws](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Applicative_functors#Applicative_functor_laws) and one of them is:

```
u <*> pure y = pure ($ y) <*> u -- Interchange
```

i.e.

```
Branch t1 t2 <*> Leaf a
```

should be the same as:

```
pure ($ a) <*> Branch t1 t2
```

But according to this implementation:

```
Leaf f <*> t = f <$> t
```

It should be equal to:

```
($ a) <$> Branch t1 t2
```

i. e

```
Branch (fmap ($ a) t1) (fmap ($ a) t2)
```

Hence, in the particular case of `Branch (Leaf (+1)) (Leaf (+2)) <*> Leaf 7`, it should return:

```
Branch (Leaf 8) (Leaf 9)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
What does ($ a) mean ?

Comment: The link I've provided (about laws) contains this information: ($ y) is the function that supplies y as argument to another function. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Higher-order_functions#Application

Comment: @MMacphail `($ a)` is the same as `(\f -> f a)` the function which takes a function `f` and applies it to `a`.

Comment: @MMacphail, more generally, if `*&*` is an operator, `(*&* y)` (called an *operator section*) is the same as `\x -> x *&* y`. In this case, the operator is `$`, defined `f $ a = f a`. You can use an operator on the other side, too: `(x *&*) = \y -> x *&* y`

Comment: @IgorDrozdov Is the last equation in author's code correct? Namely, `Branch t1 t2 <*> Branch t3 t4 = Branch (t1 <*> t3) (t2 <*> t4)` ... Intuitively it doesn't feel right  and  `Branch t1 t2 <*> t = Branch (t1 <*> t) (t2 <*> t)` feels better but I cannot come up with any example or proof that would support this feeling.